# Object in one class is the instance variable in the other. Relation between those classes?

Tags: java

The instance variable in one class is an object in another class! What is the relation between the 2 classes. Both are in the same package.

Comment: This is called [Has-a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) relationship.

Comment: Sounds like a "real-time" question :)

Comment: What you're referring to is composition (rather than inheritance): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two classes are certainly related i.e. they have an ***Association***. But, the nature of their relationship could either be an *Aggregation* or *Composition*. To give you an example and thereby explain how it's different than *Inheritance*; consider the following classes:

- `Shape` (Base class; can be *abstract*)
- `Circle`, `Triangle`, `Square` etc. (Derived classes)
- `Line`, `Colour` (Classes used in *aggregation* or *composition*)

Any of the derived classes: `Circle`, `Triangle`, `Square` **"IS-A"** `Shape` as well. This is ***Inheritance*** where the subclass like *`Circle extends Shape`* superclass. All *public* & *protected* attributes (like *area*) and behaviour (say, *`move()`*) are inherited and accessible to the child classes.

Now, each of these shapes would be composed of `Line`(s) and would have a `Colour` i.e. actual instance of these classes would be present as *attributes (properties)* inside the shape class objects.

This is known as a **"HAS-A"** relationship because a `Shape`, say, a `Square` *has-a* `Colour` and four `Line`(s). This relationship can be further observed in the following two forms:

- ***Aggregation*** (is a directional association)
  Here, `Shape` subclasses and `Colour` have an aggregation. This relationship is ***many-to-one*** i.e. a shape can have only one colour and one or more shapes can have the same colour.
- ***Composition*** (is a stronger form of aggregation)
  Here, `Shape` subclasses and `Line`(s) have a ***one-to-many*** composition. The difference is that the lifetime of a contained object is dependent on its container.

For example, if a `Triangle` is destroyed, it's `Line`(s) get destroyed as well. On the other hand, if it was painted red, the corresponding `Colour` object still remains alive since as part of a *many-to-one* relationship it may possibly be referenced by other shape objects as well.

***References*** :
[Has-A relationships (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a)
[Composition over Inheritance (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)
[Prefer composition over inheritance? (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002/1237040)
[Aggregation vs Composition vs Inheritance vs Association vs Dependency](http://www.garrypassarella.co.uk/2012/10/05/aggregation-vs-composition-vs-inheritance-vs-association-vs-dependency/)